# Task with event control in fork join_none causes unexpected behavior

Tags: system-verilog

Task with event control in fork join_none causes unexpected behavior

```
    The expected behavior in the above code is as follows:
    thread(0) is called, creates process waiting for multi[0]
    thread(1) is called, creates new process waiting for multi[1]
    thread(2) is called, creates new process waiting for multi[2]
    thread(3) is called, creates new process waiting for multi[3]
    when multi[0] is called, ack[0] should go high
    when multi[1] is called, ack[1] should go high
    when multi[2] is called, ack[2] should go high
    when multi[3] is called, ack[3] should go high
```

But this does not happen. Only ack[3] goes high.
Here is the terminal output:

```
    rst 0
    rst 1
    rst 2
    rst 3
    ack 3
    ack 3
    ack 3
    ack 3
```

---

```
module quick_test_tb_top;

logic clk;
logic rst;

always #5 clk <= ~clk;

logic [3:0] req;
logic [3:0] ack;

task thread(int j);
    ack[j] = 0;
    $display("rst %d", j);
    @(posedge req[j]);
    $display("ack for req %d", j);
    ack[j] = 1;
endtask

initial begin
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
        automatic int j = i;
        fork
            thread(j);
        join_none
    end
end

initial begin
    req = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) @(posedge clk);
    req = 15;
end

initial begin
  clk = 0;
  rst = 1;
  #10
  #1000 $stop;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: @toolic The minimal reproducible example is already shown above. Please just paste the code into a testbench.

The expected output to be is also already written in the post above. All ack's should go high, not just ack[3]

Comment: @MahmoudMaarouf, It's not a complete reproducible example. You never declared clk or described how it behaves. And you are missing `module/endmodule`

Comment: @dave_59
I apologize for the inconvenience, please look at my updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `task thread` which has a static lifetime. That means there is only one static argument variable `j` for all concurrent calls to `thread`. It would have helped to declare task argument `j` with a different name. Let's rename it to `t`. That's different from the automatic variable `j` you declared inside the `for` loop. Although you pass different values into `thread(j)`, when it reaches the event control, the argument gets overwritten. You need to declare `thread` with an automatic lifetime.

```
module top;
  logic [3:0] multi;
  logic [3:0] ack;
  task automatic thread(int t); // t has an automatic lifetime
    ack[t] = 0;
    $display("rst %d", t);
    @(posedge multi[t]);
    $display("ack %d", t);
    ack[t] = 1;
  endtask

  initial 
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
      fork
        automatic int j = i;
        thread(j);
      join_none
  
  initial begin
    multi = '0;
    #200;
    multi = '1;
  end
  
endmodule
```

You might want to read my article: "[The life of a SystemVerilog variable](https://resources.sw.siemens.com/en-US/white-paper-the-life-of-a-systemverilog-variable)"

Comment: Thank you Dave!  Making the task automatic fixed it